# Не работает отладка в Local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Не работает отладка в Local IIS, пробовал на 3 ПК безрезультатно везде тажа ситуация. Проект на ASP.NET MVC 5. Как включить ее (в IIS Express 10 работает без проблем).

1. ASP.NET MVC 5
2. Режим отладки в Local IIS
3. VS 2017 v15.9.6
4. Вывод VS сообщает только о загруженных и выгруженных библиотеках и больше ни чего криминального.
5. [Лог](https://yadi.sk/d/LHNbSFNIBzUNqQ)

Поправка.
1. Я немного поторопился с вопросом, он у меня отрабатывает точку останова только после обновления страницы браузера, а при первом запуске проекта почему то не срабатывает.

Comment: поподробнее пишите....скрины, ошибки приветствуются)

Comment: а какие простите картинки я вам вышлю, если отладчик просто не реагирует на точки останова

Comment: в каком режиме запускаете? целевая платформа? версия студии? настройки локального веб сервера? если кора, то и настройка kestrel. логи iis express (или какой там у вас), настройки отладчика....да хоть что нибудь покажите. Пример кода со скрином, где не заходит в точку, но вы ждете.И так вопрос не понятный, дак вы еще и ванговать просите. В лучшем случае никто не ответит.